# Multiple version of pdftex side-by-side

Tags: pdftex

For testing purposes, I want to set up another version of `pdftex`. The standard version, residing under `/usr/lib/texmf/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex` should be left untouched. I managed to compile `pdftex`, and I guess the right place for it is `/usr/local/share/texmf/bin/x86_64-linux/`, with a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`. How do I tell `kpathsea` to use this new version?

Comment: Perhaps do a full(ish) install of TeX under `/usr/local`, `kpathsea` and all, and switch your `PATH` (or run by complete path). I don't know if both versions will get messed up, for absolute certainty I'd do the building _without_ TeX installed. Or can you use a virtual machine for the doctored TeX installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This receipe worked for me, installing a new pdftex in TEXMFHOME.

```
#!/bin/bash

## run this script in the top directory of the freshly unpacked pdftex sources
## it is assumed that TEXMF contains TEXMFHOME before the other TEXMF trees, see texmf.cnf

## build pdftex
./build-pdftex.sh

## directory for pdftex in TEXMFHOME
mkdir -p ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux

## directory for pdftex.pool and formats in TEXMFHOME
mkdir -p ${HOME}/texmf/web2c

## bring pdftex and pool file to TEXMFHOME
cp build-pdftex/texk/web2c/pdftex ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux

## bring pdftex.pool to TEXMFHOME
cp build-pdftex/texk/web2c/pdftex.pool ${HOME}/texmf/web2c

## make a link to texmf.cnf in TEXMFHOME so the new pdftex will find it
ln -s /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux/texmf.cnf

## put a link to the new pdftex that is in the PATH
ln -s ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux/pdftex ${HOME}/bin/pdftex

## let kpsetool see the new texmf.cnf and pdftex.pool
texhash

## create formats, using the new pdftex, and the ini files from the existing TeX installation
pdftex -ini -etex pdftex.ini
pdftex -ini -etex pdflatex.ini

## bring formats to TEXMFHOME
cp pdftex.fmt pdflatex.fmt ${HOME}/texmf/web2c

## make pdflatex a symlink to pdftex
ln -s ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux/pdftex ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux/pdflatex

## make pdflatex findable
ln -s ${HOME}/texmf/bin/`arch`-linux/pdflatex ${HOME}/bin/pdflatex

## tell kpsetool about the formats
texhash
```