# Patched version of pdftex does not see what kpsewhich sees

Tags: pdftex, paths, filesystem-access, build-system, pdf-a

I have TeX Live version 2013.30973-7 running on ArchLinux. I want to use a [patched version of pdftex](http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4341&group_id=106&atid=493) to create valid PDF/A-1b documents.

I have an issue using the patched version after compilation. I followed [this](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Notes_on_TeX_Live_setup#Run_pdftex_compiled_from_sources) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97686/multiple-version-of-pdftex-side-by-side) instructions. However, I am stuck at the point when trying to create the format files:

```
pdftex2 -ini -translate-file=cp227.tcx '*pdfetex.ini'
pdflatex2 -ini -translate-file=cp227.tcx '*pdflatex.ini'
```

Output for first command (likewise for the other):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `pdfetex.ini'.
<*> pdftex.ini
```

The files do exist in my `texmf-dist` tree and are found by `kpsewhich`:

```
# kpsewhich 'pdfetex.ini'
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini
```

I also tried running the command with the full path and copying the files into the working directory, but nothing worked. When using the full path, it complained about the next file. Can someone point me to what I am missing?

---

*Update 1*: As suggested in the source and instructions, I used `build-pdftex.sh` to configure and compile `pdftex`. An interesting flag set in there is `--without-system-kpathsea` which I figured might be the reason why the compiled `pdftex` does not see what the system `kpsewhich` sees. Also other system libs are disabled, which are all explicitly enabled in the [gentoo ebuild](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/dev-tex/pdftex/pdftex-1.40.11.ebuild?view=markup). Unfortunately, the compilation fails when switching to `--with-system-kpathsea` -- missing `kpathsea` header files.

I downloaded also the TeX Live 2013 source. TeX Live has an updated version of `pdftex`: The latest standalone version of `pdftex` is 1.40.11 (at least I do not find another) at [Sarovar](http://sarovar.org/projects/pdftex/), while  TeX Live 2013 has 1.40.14. Is pdftex now developed in TeX Live?

---

*Update 2:* I managed to compile (both patched and unpatched) pdftex 1.40.14 from TeX Live 2013, also using `--with-system-kpathsea`. However, when running the compiled pdftex, in any circumstances, the very same error occurs.

---

*Update 3:* pdftex is in fact developed at [supelec.fr](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/pdftex/) (see [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-December/034569.html)). Further, when putting the binary to `/usr/bin`, the compiled version works fine (see [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2013q4/002709.html)). For the local installation I am still unsure how to do it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path name of the ini file, i.e., executing `pdftex2 -ini -translate-file=cp227.tcx '/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini'` (possibly without the "forward ticks," i.e., `'`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It then complains for another file (`I can't find file 'etex.src'`). `kpsewhich etex.src` gives
`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/etex.src` as its location. Interestingly, it does not complain for the line `\input pdftexconfig.tex`, which is before `\input etex.src`, whose file is also in another directory (`/etc/texmf/tex/generic/config`).

Comment: This won't solve this problem but I think if you are going to do this, it would be better to ditch the version of texlive from the official repos and install TeX Live from upstream under /usr/local. This has several advantages. First, it keeps anything you do out of pacman's way. Second, it means you have an installation which is truly vanilla and don't have to worry about differences in Arch's implementation when following instructions etc. It is pretty easy to install a dummy texlive package to keep pacman happy if you have an editor or something which requires it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting the correctly compiled executables to `/usr/bin`, everything works as expected. As I struggled quite a bit correctly compiling it, I think it will be useful to have an up-to-date guide to get `pdftex` from current sources. 
A big thank you to the helpful people at the [tex live](http://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2013q4/thread.html) and [tlbuild](http://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2013q4/thread.html) mailing lists. Here's the guide:

---

### How to build and install `pdftex/pdflatex` from source

**1.) Get the sources** with `rsync`  from Tex Live (change if you want version control):

```
rsync -a --delete --exclude=.svn tug.org::tldevsrc/Build/source source
```

---

**2.) Patch pdftex** in `source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir`, if you want.

---

**3.) Build the sources** using the following script (modified from [1](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/branches/stable/source/build-pdftex.sh?view=markup&revision=675&root=pdftex) and [2](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/dev-tex/pdftex/pdftex-1.40.11.ebuild?view=markup)):

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
# build-pdftex.sh: script to build pdftex from a subset of TeX Live sources

topDir=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)
pdftexDir=$topDir/source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir

if [ ! -d $pdftexDir ]; then
    echo "$pdftexDir not found"
    exit -1
fi
GENTOO_CFG_OPTS="\
    --disable-cxx-runtime-hack  \
    --disable-all-pkgs      \
    --disable-ptex        \
    --enable-pdftex       \
    --disable-native-texlive-build \
    --without-mf-x-toolkit    \
    --without-x         \
    --disable-shared      \
    --disable-largefile     \
    --with-system-xpdf      \
    --with-system-zlib      \
    --with-system-pnglib    \
    --disable-multiplatform   \
    --with-system-kpathsea    \
    --with-system-ptexenc"

CFG_OPTS="$GENTOO_CFG_OPTS"

buildDir=$(pwd)/build-pdftex
rm -rf $buildDir && mkdir $buildDir && cd $buildDir

export CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash
$topDir/source/configure $CFG_OPTS "$@" 2>&1 | tee configure.log

# try to find gnu make; we may need it
MAKE=make
if make -v 2>&1| grep "GNU Make" >/dev/null; then
    echo "Your make is a GNU-make; I will use that"
elif gmake -v >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    MAKE=gmake
    echo "You have a GNU-make installed as gmake; I will use that"
else
    echo "I can't find a GNU-make; I'll try to use make and hope that works."
    echo "If it doesn't, please install GNU-make."
fi

$MAKE | tee make.log
(cd $buildDir/texk/web2c; $MAKE pdftex) 2>&1 | tee -a make.log
```

---

**4.) Move the compiled `pdftex` to `/usr/bin`, and generate and install required format files** 
Execute as su (`su -`)!

```
#!/bin/sh
# mv-compiled-pdftex.sh
SUFFIX="-newest"

sudo cp build-pdftex/texk/web2c/pdftex /usr/bin/pdftex${SUFFIX}
sudo cp build-pdftex/texk/web2c/pdftex /usr/bin/pdflatex${SUFFIX}

PDFTEXFMTDIR=$(dirname $(sudo kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt) )
echo "Putting format files to $PDFTEXFMTDIR" # check that this is the location you want!

pdftex${SUFFIX} -ini -translate-file=cp227.tcx '*pdfetex.ini'
pdflatex${SUFFIX} -ini -translate-file=cp227.tcx '*pdflatex.ini'

sudo mv -v pdfetex.fmt ${PDFTEXFMTDIR}/pdftex${SUFFIX}.fmt
sudo mv -v pdflatex.fmt ${PDFTEXFMTDIR}/pdflatex${SUFFIX}.fmt

sudo texhash
```

Using this script, you will have the executables available as `pdftex-newest` and `pdflatex-newest` and working. For a local installation (`~/texmf` and `~/bin`, have a look at [this answer](http://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2013q4/002712.html), and adapt the code I used [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tlbuild/2013q4/002711.html).