# kpsewhich finds correct local package; pdflatex does not

Tags: texlive, openbsd

I am running Tex Live 2013 from OpenBSD-current. The versions of biblatex and biblatex-chicago seem to be a bit old there, which is in turn causing some of my documents to not compile.

I've downloaded the latest versions of these two packages from CTAN and placed them in my `~/texmf`folder. `kpsewhich` seems to find the correct versions:

```
% kpsewhich biblatex.sty biblatex-chicago.sty
/home/peter/texmf/tex/biblatex/latex/biblatex.sty
/home/peter/texmf/tex/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty
```

Compiling a document where I import biblatex-chicago fails. I believe this is because pdflatex is finding the old version of these packages in spite of kpsewhich seeing the correct versions:

```
% pdflatex summaries.tex                     
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013-OpenBSD_Ports)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./summaries.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex1.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-authordate.bbx)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-authordate.cbx)
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))

Package biblatex Warning: 'labelyear' option is deprecated, use 'labeldate' ins
tead.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \DeclareLabelyear 
                             [music,review,video]{\field {eventyear}\field {...
l.92 \csuse{cms@\cms@style}
```

I found [this question that describes this issue with a patched version of pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150088/patched-version-of-pdftex-does-not-see-what-kpsewhich-sees). However, since I'm using the packaged version of texlive, I'm not entirely sure rebuilding pdftex is the right approach here. I'm begining to suspect this is a bug in the OpenBSD texlive package, but am posting this here as a question just in case I'm simply being daft.

Comment: Your file locations look odd: should be `/home/peter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty` rather than `/home/peter/texmf/tex/biblatex/latex/biblatex.sty`, for example.

Comment: Use kpsewhich as
`kpsewhich --progname=pdflatex biblatex.sty`
which shows the location where pdflatex
finds `biblatex.sty`.

Comment: Joseph is correct. I botched the installation into my local texmf folder. Fixing the paths issues fixed the problem. And an extra thanks to Akira for pointing me to `--progname=pdflatex`. That clearly indicated that it was looking to the wrong location. Thus confirming my fears that I was simply being daft :-)

Comment: @JosephWright An answer?