# How to have “preprocessor” flags in LaTeX

Tags: macros, conditionals

C programmers often use constructs like

```c
#ifdef foo
    printf("foo is defined ");
#endif
#ifndef foo
    printf("foo is not defined ");
#endif
```

to select certain code-paths during the compilation process, by passing the compiler flag like `-Dfoo` or just sticking a `#define foo 0` somewhere in the code.

Is this possible in LaTeX too? So I am looking for something like

```
\ifdef foo{
   short summary, tldr
 }
\ifndef foo{
   long explanation
}
```

This can be particularly helpful for producing short summary documents from existing TeX files containing long descriptions. I would like to be able to pass
something similar to `-Dfoo` as a compiler flag, or just define the `foo` somewhere near the top of the Latex file, just as I would do in the C case.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461982/134574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\ifdefined` to check whether a macro is defined.  To check whether a macro is *not* defined, reverse the conditional by prefixing `\unless`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\newcommand\foo{}
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\foo
   short summary, tldr
\fi
\unless\ifdefined\foo
   long explanation
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt MkIV you can achieve this behaviour using Modes.

```
\starttext

\startmode[foo]
   short summary, tldr
\stopmode
\startnotmode[foo]
   long explanation
\stopnotmode

\stoptext
```

The great thing about ConTeXt modes is that you can switch them on from the command line of the `context` program.

```
$ context --mode=foo test.mkvi
```