# Is it possible to `\include`/`\input` a text depending on the language set on babel or polyglossia

Tags: languages, input, programming, include

> I would like to know if it is possible to conditionally require, in a given document, the inclusion of a chapter or the input of a particular piece of text, depending on the language set on `babel` or in `polyglossia`.

I mean something similar to the mechanism used by the package `translations` for the customization of a document according to the setting of its main language. Precisely, I would like that, after setting the main document language by

```
\usepackage[lang]{babel}
```

or

```
\setmainlanguage{lang},
```

a language file `text_lang` is automatically included in the text: : specialist in documentation design call this language conditioned parts "tags".

> Is this possible and, if so, could you address me to the relevant packages or show an example code?

Comment: You mean like in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461973/134574 ?

Comment: You can check the current language with https://ctan.org/pkg/iflang or https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang

Comment: Note that there are differences in the way `babel` and `polyglossia` handle language variant/dialects. `babel` usually assigns a new language name (if you will), for example `ngerman` for German with new orthography rules and `naustrian` for Austrian German with new orthography rules. But `polyglossia` would use the same base language in that case (`german`) and would handle the new/old orthography rules and German/Austrian/Swiss German with additional properties that are hard to detect from the outside

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thank you very much! I am a bit perplexed from the fact that I was not able to find it by searching the TEX.SE: however this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @moewe: so for `polyglossia` it would be more difficult to conditionally import text in different languages sharing a common linguistic root. However this is not a problem for me at present, since I am trying to discriminate between quite different languages. Anyway, thank you so much for the packages you suggested/highlighted.

Comment: I wouldn't say *different languages with a common linguistic root* (since that seems to be quite general and would in my Book include for example German and Dutch), it is more about variants/dialects of one language (though there could be some disagreement whether or not something is a variant or a different language in its own right). In the end this is about how `polyglossia` handles these languages.