# Conditioning comments

Tags: programming, comments

I'm trying to condition comments. I got some information about if/else structures in Latex and here is my first idea :

```
\newcounter{student}
\setcounter{student}{1}
\ifnum \value{student}=1 {\begin{comment}}\fi
text
\ifnum \value{student}=1 {\end{comment}}\fi
```

The compilation fails when I try to execute this code. I think it's because when the first condition is verified being true, the second one has not been processed yet. So the \end{comment} is not in the document yet. I guess Latex is scanning the document to search where is the \end{document} before executing the second \ifnum. As it doesn't find it, it crashes.

With really little hope, I tried :

```
\ifnum \value{student}=1 {%}\fi text
```

but it fails for obvious reasons.

Do you have some ideas to condition the inclusion of parts of a document please ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: When `\begin{comment}` is found, TeX is operating normally, so it expands the `\ifnum` test. But once `\begin{comment}` starts, it looks at the document line by line looking for _exactly_ `\end{comment}`. As that isn't found, chaos ensues. See the `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` commands of the `comment` package.

Comment: May also be useful to you: [Generating multiple versions of a document using options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461973/134574).

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answers !