# Automatically remove \ifthenelse

Tags: scripts, parsing, ifthenelse, awk

Let's assume that you have a single LaTeX source file that can compile two arts of documents: a main conference paper and its extended long version. Inside, you use `\ifthenese` to produce the two versions. Example:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\documentclass{article}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{false}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{Stuff for the TR}{Stuff for the main paper}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible, say, via some script (`sed`, `elisp`, `awk`, `m4`, ...), to produce the source LaTeX file for the main conference paper out of such a source? Example:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\documentclass{article}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{false}
\begin{document}
Stuff for the main paper
\end{document}
```

You may assume that every occurence of an `\ifthenelse` starts `\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}` (i.e., the macro is used for a single purpose only), that these occurences may be nested up to two levels, and that the two arguments of the command can be of any size:  empty, a word, several words, or many lines, including empty lines.  The command `\ifthenelse{...}{...}{...}` itself may start anywhere in a line and end anywhere in the same or in a different line.
You may assume that all the braces `{` `}` are properly nested, that this nesting may go arbitrarily deep anywhere in the LaTeX source (including both branches of the `\ifthenelse`), that all the comments `%...` have been already emptied, that there are neither `\include`s nor `\input`s left, and that the end-of-line mark follows the UNIX convention.

Ideally, your script should throw an error if a wrong number of arguments is given to `\ifthenelse`, such as in

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{A}%

More text
```

Comment: Do you know `docstrip`? See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461982/134574

Comment: No, with docstrip the guard (which acts as the conditional) _must_ be at the beginning of the line. But it produces each version of the document out of the box. You `\ifthenelse` could be replaced by `%<techrep>Stuff for the TR[imagine a line break here]%<paper>Stuff for the main paper`. And things common to both would be delimited by `%<*techrep|paper>` and `%</techrep|paper>`. Adding a third version would be almost trivial. I know your question is not about `docstrip`. I was just showing the tool :-) Anyhow, I think you would find more sed/awk experts at stackoverflow or unix & linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions in Vim, probably similar in other programs:

```
:%s/\\ifthenelse{[^}]*}{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}/\1
```

That keeps the first branch; if you want to keep the second, change `\1` to `\2`.

Comment: I think you're missing a `}` at the end of the true branch: `:%s/\\ifthenelse{[^}]*}{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}/\1`. This won't work if there are braces inside the branches though...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, thanks, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of PhelypeOleinik, but without having to comment all the lines, perhaps the perl script `srcredact` (part of TeXLive 2019) can be of help. This is my modified example file (`MdAyq6-doc.tex`):

```
%<*ALL>
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Common text
%</ALL>
%<*techrep>
Stuff for the TR
%</techrep>
%<*maindoc>
Stuff for the main paper
%</maindoc>
%<*ALL>
\end{document}
%</ALL>
```

Now from the command line:

```
[pablo@worktex forum] $ srcredact -l MdAyq6-doc.tex 
ALL
maindoc
techrep
[pablo@worktex forum] $ srcredact -e techrep MdAyq6-doc.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Common text
Stuff for the TR
\end{document}
[pablo@worktex forum] $ srcredact -e maindoc MdAyq6-doc.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Common text
Stuff for the main paper
\end{document}
[pablo@worktex forum] $ srcredact -e ALL MdAyq6-doc.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Common text
\end{document}
```

Here we see the output on screen, if we want to generate the output file just add `> file.tex` at the end of the line. As follows:

```
$ srcredact -e techrep MdAyq6-doc.tex > techrep.tex
```

and the file `techrep.tex` will be created.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Common text
Stuff for the TR
\end{document}
```

It's not as powerful as docstript, but it does a great job.

**EDIT**
If the idea is to remove using *regular expressions*, it's not that easy, the escaped braces inside are a mess, but, something can be done using `Perl` :). Assuming that the syntax of your input file is valid, with the following `rmifthen.pl` script it is possible:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.26;
use autodie;
use File::Basename;
use open ':locale';

## Args
@ARGV == 1  or die "Use: $0 <file (La)TeX to be processed>\n";
my $input_file = shift;
-f $input_file or die "ERROR: Can't find [$input_file]\n";

## Extension
my @SuffixList = ('.tex', '', '.ltx');
my ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($input_file, @SuffixList);
$ext = '.tex' if not $ext;

## Read file
open my $TEXINPUT, '<', $input_file;
my $ltxfile;
 {
    local $/;
    $ltxfile = <$TEXINPUT>;
 }
close   $TEXINPUT;

## Change escaped braces to a character that is not in the text
$ltxfile =~ s/\\[{]/«/g;
$ltxfile =~ s/\\[}]/»/g;

## Two groups of captures: the complete ifthenelse, and the true ifthenelse.
my $ifthenelse = qr/
    (
        \\ifthenelse (?&condicion_rx)\s*
            (?<expVerdadero> (?&expVerdadero_rx)\s*)
            (?&expFalsa_rx)
    )

    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<condicion_rx>    (?&texto_rx))
        (?<expVerdadero_rx> (?&texto_rx))
        (?<expFalsa_rx>     (?&texto_rx))
        (?<texto_rx>  ( [{] (?: [^{}]++ | (?-1) )*+ [}]  ) )
    )
/sx;

## We look for ifthenelse throughout the document
my @posiciones;

# Every time we find an ifthenelse mark, we keep the initial, final
# position of the whole mark, And the text of the true clause
while ($ltxfile =~ /$ifthenelse/g) {
    push @posiciones, [ $-[1], $+[1], $+{expVerdadero} ];
}

## We replace the whole ifthenelse brand, with the true expression, except the braces
for my $pos_ref (reverse @posiciones) {
    substr($ltxfile, $pos_ref->[0], $pos_ref->[1] - $pos_ref->[0])
        = substr $pos_ref->[2], 1, -2;
}

## We recovered the escaped braces.
$ltxfile =~ s/«/\\{/g;
$ltxfile =~ s/»/\\}/g;

## Write file
open my $SALIDA, '>', "$name-out$ext";
print   $SALIDA $ltxfile;
close   $SALIDA;

__END__
```

With this example file:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{false}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{Este es texto
con el que {deseo quedarme} incluidas las llaves \{ que no están
escapadas dentro de el, pero sin las llaves exteriores
}{Este es texto NO lo deseo, también {puede llevar llaves}  \}
que no están escapadas} %
TEXTO TEXTO
TEXTO TEXTO \ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{Otro texto
con el que \{deseo quedarme\} incluidas las llaves \{ \}
que no están escapadas
}{Este es texto {NO lo deseo}, también puede llevar llaves \{
que no están \} escapadas}
TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO
\end{document}
```

running:

```
perl rmifthen.pl file.tex
```

we get:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{false}
\begin{document}
Este es texto
con el que {deseo quedarme} incluidas las llaves \{ que no están
escapadas dentro de el, pero sin las llaves exteriores %
TEXTO TEXTO
TEXTO TEXTO Otro texto
con el que \{deseo quedarme\} incluidas las llaves \{ \}
que no están escapadas
TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO
\end{document}
```

With your MWE the output is what you propose. I think this is more than you were looking for.

Greetings and good luck with your next conference.

Comment: @MdAyq6 Check my update.